# I get a message that says “Video not Found or Access denied” even with a PUBLIC LINK

Tags: video, google-cloud-storage, google-apis-explorer

Can you please help. I have uploaded a video to Google Cloud Storage and have made it public. I have inserted the link on my website builder (runs a JW Player) and I get the message "Video not Found or Access denied”

I have tried everything I can think of. Please, if you have any tips I am all ears.

The link to the video is: http://storage.googleapis.com/sonharerealizar/Módulos%20do%20Treinamento/Modulo01.mp4

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you have to check the ACL for the object as well as for the bucket. It seems that the object you were trying to access is public but not the bucket or vice-versa.